# How can I bookmark the left page of a PDF in Preview?

Tags: pdf, preview

In Preview, Command-D will allow you to bookmark the current page of the PDF for later reference.  However, when viewing the PDF in two-up mode (Command-3), it will *always* bookmark the right-hand page.  How can I bookmark the left-hand page for those times when it's that page precisely that I want to bookmark?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do that with Bookmarks, but I use a work around till Apple does something.

Instead of bookmarks I use Highlights and Notes (alt+cmd+4)

Then I place a Note on appropriate page (left or right) or anywhere.

The advantage is I can make comments in the note.

Example:

[image: notes]